# Proxying client side requests with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, fetch, reverse-proxy

I am new to Nginx and currently I am working on a project that has an api running on the server side that serves data. The api gets all of its traffic from a reverse proxy in Nginx. The proxy looks something like this:

```
server {
    server_name name.com;
    listen 80;

    # headers set here #        

    location /api1/ {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8888; #api location
        proxy_redirect  off;
     }
}
```

I have no problem talking to the api from the server side with my program that is operating on port 80. I get a 404 when I try to make an request to the api from the client side with the Fetch web api.

My fetch looks like this:

```
fetch('/api1/some/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => doSomething(data))
.catch(error => throw error)
```

Is this considered a cross origin request? Do I need to configure nginx to be able to handle requests from the client? Am I completely off the mark with how I am using these technologies? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-origin requests and 404's are not directly related. Cross-origin has to do with security, not with availability. Could you explain where fetch is running? Since you're not providing a hostname in your request it's very likely you're not hitting "name.com" but the default server.

Comment: @Melvyn The fetch runs on initial load of the browser and the request is being done on "name.com". So the url that the fetch will go to would be name.com/api1/some/endpoint/, at least that is the intention. In the response object of the fetch, the url that is listed is the correct one.